# How to return data pulled from python requests call into json

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to make a GHE API call and convert the returned data into JSON. I am sure this is fairly simple (my current code writes the data into `a .txt` file) but I am incredibly new to python.

I am having a hard time understanding how to use `json.dumps`.

```
import requests
import json

GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_TOKEN = 'token xxx'

SEARCH_QUERY = "Evidence+locker+Seed+in:readme"

headers = {
    'Authorization': GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_TOKEN,
}

url = "https://github.ibm.com/api/v3/search/repositories?q=" + SEARCH_QUERY
#Setup url to include GHE api endpoint and the search query

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('./evidencelockerevidence.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(response.text)
    #writes to a .txt file the evidence fetched from GHE
```

Rather than the last two lines of functional code writing the data into `a .txt` file I would like to return it as JSON object in the same directory.

Comment: What do you mean by JSON object in the same directory? You want to use a file, not a DB file, like JSON object.?

Comment: sorry I meant to return a .json with the output in the same directory I am operating in

Comment: Please check my answer. If it is not enough I will further edit. File extension is not that important for programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.dumps` simply stringify, thus, serialize your JSON object so you can store it as a plain text file. Its counterpart is `json.loads`.

```
f = open('a.jsonl', 'wt')
f.write(json.dumps(jobj))
```

People usually write one JSON object per line, a.k.a, `jsonl` format.

`json.dump` directly store your JSON object to a file. Its counterpart is `json.load`.

```
json.dump(jobj, open('a.json', 'wt'))
```

A `json` format file contains only one JSON object in a single line or multiple lines.

Comment: Ok so if I am trying to end up with a .json file at the end I need to use json.load instead? I just am making a GHE API call and trying to make the result a .json

Comment: Yes, `jobj = json.load(open('a.json'))`. Would you please accept it it it was helpful?